# Downvotes on Android app do not show in achievements list

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

I got a downvote on EL&U yesterday and it does not show up on the Android app, but it shows up on the website.

View in the app:

> [image]

View on the website:

> [image]

App version is 1.0.83 on a Samsung Note 5 with Android version 5.1.1.

Comment: Hmm, weird... it's shown when I downvoted an answer (-1), though your case is different since your post was downvoted. Can you try downvoting an answer and see if it's reflected on the app?

Comment: Downvoting an answer is reflected.